# .put() update-> deprecated method tried using updateOne() didn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

.put(function(req,res) { console.log(req.body.content); Article.update( {title:req.params.specificarticle}, {title:req.body.title, content:req.body.content}, {overwrite:true}, function(err) { if(!err){ res.send("Successfully updated article"); } } ); });

Comment: If you have a question about a warning message, please post the entire message (and a question).

Comment: Error : read ECONNREST

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I  refferd to some docs in google and i came to know that `Model.update()`menthod is deprecated .i tried using updateOne() but it didn't work, after some research i tried using updateMany() and guess what it worked

Code which didn't work:

```
Article.updateOne(
        {title:req.params.specificarticle},
        {title:req.body.title, content:req.body.content},
        {overwrite:true},
        function(err)
        {
            if(!err){
            res.send("Successfully updated article");
            }
        }
        );
```

Code which worked:

```
console.log(req.params.specificarticle);
    console.log(req.body.title);
    Article.updateMany(
        {title:req.params.specificarticle},{$set:{title:req.body.title, content:req.body.content}},
        function(err)
        {
            if(!err){
            res.send("Successfully updated article");
            }
        }
        );
```